# Why do I get hostname: Name or service not known error?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, dpkg

I'm getting this error when ever I install any packages via `apt-get`:

```
hostname: Name or service not known
dpkg: error processing ssmtp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libt1-5 (5.1.2-3.4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up php5-gd (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ssmtp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: I had the same issue, the problem was related to the fact that the DNS did not help any entry for the hostname - therefore the FQDN was unavailable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Solution:

*(These types of problems don't have good solutions. But only some haking-ish)*

You should first try this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If it doesn't work, process with *haking-ish* solution.

Try temporarily moving the configuration script of `ssmtp`.

1. Open a terminal and execute this command to move them to the current dir

   ```
     sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/ssmtp* .
   ```
2. Then try using `apt-get`

#### The cause of the problem:

The previous installation or removal might not completed successfully, leaving some configuration step to be done for `ssmtp` package. Since, dpkg won't progress without first completing the steps, subsequent use of `apt-get` now get stuck on that step.

Answer (score 23):

run `hostname --fqdn`

If you get an error, edit /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts with a proper hostname.

Then `aptitude install ssmtp` again to get it to install.

Comment: "proper" means: must contain a period and no spaces.

Comment: the hostname from `/etc/hostname` must match the one in `etc/hosts` 127.0.0.1 section

Answer (score 15):

Editing of `/etc/hosts` did the trick. The file `/etc/hostname` was correct with containing only `server.exmaple.com`

But the hosts was not correct

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 server
```

I changed it to this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain  localhost
192.168.xxx.xxx  server.example.com   server
```

then I ran `hostname -f` (short for `hostname --fqdn`) and got the following.

```
server.example.com
```

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your internet connection is not working properly.
Specifically I think your DNS is not resolving properly.

try to add the line

```
nameserver 80.80.80.80
```

to your `/etc/resolv.conf`

This will add the freenom DNS server temporarily (until the next boot)

Comment: That is a generated file. How do I manage it?

Comment: @chovy if you're still wondering about this, it's safe to go ahead and `sudoedit /etc/resolv.conf` to replace whatever address is there with `8.8.8.8` to resolve temporary DNS issues. The file will be regenerated on the next boot, so you can't do anything too disastrous here unless rebooting isn't an option

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error this morning, and it turned out that the hostname was misspelled in `/etc/hostname`.  Correcting this so it agreed with the hostname spelling in `/etc/hosts` cleared up the problem.  The `hostname -b -F /etc/hostname` command that runs at boot time apparently cannot complete unless `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` agree.

Comment: This answer resolved it for me: First I made sure `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` agree. Then I ran the "command that runs at boot time", only without the `-b` flag (as it merely allows the specified file to be non-existant, but it is here). And bang: `hostname --fqdn` returns proper FQDN again.

Comment: Ad I think the hostname, you choose must contain at least one period

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten the message on my home network on an Ubuntu system with a dynamically assigned IP address from a router providing a combined DHCP and DNS server for my network.

The message: `hostname: Name or service not known` can be caused by such a device going down, if only for an instant.

For example this can happen if my home router is rebooted when my power goes out.

The problem here is that the DHCP service your network is relying upon forgets all of the IP addresses it has assigned and the associated domain names. When your computer checks the associated dns server for its own name the server no longer has it. Some DHCP servers may avoid problems by writing the assignments they have made to their disk or flash memory so nothing is lost when they restart.

---

The server may ordinarily take your *computername* from your systems DHCP request, make it *computername*.local and store that in its records, making it available in its associated DNS server simultaneously. Usually `hostname -fqdn` requests the full domain name over your network from your DNS server and if it has the record it will return that name. The `.local` suffix makes it look like a valid fully qualified domain name (though it isn't really a valid global domain name). This is why you may not have to specify a domain name manually in /etc/hosts or /etc/hostname files.

---

The DHCP server restarting may cause further problems as IP addresses may be assigned to multiple computers simultaneously, causing some not to be able to communicate. The address is assigned once before the server restarts, and again after it does.

If your DHCP server forgets its assignments the safe thing to do is to reconnect each computer it serves when it restarts. When I lost mine I simply disconnected and reconnected to my wifi access point. On a wired network you can use `ifdown` and `ifup` or simply disconnect and reconnect the network cable.
When reconnecting my system automatically uses dhclient to get a new address--my computer and the server now agree on who I am, and the message no longer appears.

If you wait long enough the DHCP lease will timeout and your system will ask for and get a new lease from the server--clearing up the problem. This will probably be hours or days later (for my server it is one day).

If you have defined a static IP name and address and if the DNS reverse look-up records are correct the problem shouldn't happen.